# If rank is not working

Tags: php, html, session

This is my first question here. This site helped me alot with my errors i had with PHP. But now i'm really stuck and don't have a clude how,
what i'm trying to get. If a user is the rank "Owner", "Admin", "Moderator" or "Editor" show Admin Panel, else keep it hidden. Everything i tryed is not working. If i change the code to the normal rank "Member", i can see the admin panel. Hope somebody can help me with this.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_rank']) <> "Owner" & "Admin" & "Moderator" & "Editor"){
    echo '<li><a href="admin.php">Admin Panel</a></li>';
}
```

Tryed this one to but is working only for the rang "Owner"

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_rank']) == "Admin" && ($_SESSION['sess_rank'] == "Owner")){
     echo "<li><a href='admin.php'>Admin Panel</a></li> ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`isset` operator is returns only boolean value

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sess_rank']) 
   && in_array($_SESSION['sess_rank'], array("Admin", "Owner"))
) {
     echo "<li><a href='admin.php'>Admin Panel</a></li> "; 
}
```

Comment: Add `)` in the condition `in_array($_SESSION['sess_rank'], array("Admin", "Owner")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OR condiftion rather than AND.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_rank'])  && ($_SESSION['sess_rank'] == "Admin" || $_SESSION['sess_rank'] == "Owner")){
                echo "<li><a href='admin.php'>Admin Panel</a></li> ";
}
```